# Sort amcharts4 Tree Map by alternative data property

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

How can I sort a amchart4 tree map by a data property other than the size of the rectangle? For example, in my chart data there is a risk level (dictates color of rectangle) and I'd like to sort the retangles by the risk level. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found was to change the `sorting` property to `"none"` and then sort the data outside of amcharts.